# telerik radgrid slow performance for large datasource in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using telerik RadGrid control in my project. It is takes lot of time to render the data on the screen. There is a list of 500 records which is used as datasource for the grid.

Disabling view state doesn't help in my case.

Surprisingly, the grid gets loaded instantly in Firefox and Chrome, however fails in IE.

Please help me out to improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as it's a 3rd party Telerik control, I doubt you can do too much about this, especially since it seems like yet another "IE sucks but everyone uses it" problem.

However, I would recommend you check out the RadGrid [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-overview.html)'s performance section (see left side navigation at this page). See if any of that applies to you.

Also, have you tried many different IE versions? I wonder if these performance problems apply to IE10/more recent IE versions (then again, most people have not downloaded IE10 yet).

Comment: The problem lies with IE 7 and 8. The environment for IE 9 and 10 is not available with right now. But I think it will appear there as well.